# How to declare and access local variables in scala template in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have code in scala template like:

```
@for(col <- List.range(0,12)) {
    <td>
        @if(col % 2 == 0) {
            @{ val letter = someMap(col) }
            <div class="z@(letter)@(letter)s"></div>
        }
    </td>
}
```

But I get compile error: value letter not found.
How can I declare variables and be able to access later in the markup like above?

Comment: Copy/paste mistake? The declaration says `va`, not `val`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare variable in a Play2 scala template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031146/declare-variable-in-a-play2-scala-template)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I have never seen @if nor have I tried PlayFramework. But if is what I think it is, it seems that when you actually try to ask for letter it's already out of scope. What happens if you re-arrange the brackets as follows?

```
@for(col <- List.range(0,12)) {
  <td>
    @if(col % 2 == 0) {
      @{val letter = someMap(col)
        <div class="z@(letter)@(letter)s"></div>
      }
    }
  </td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got this working on Play Framework 2.8.x was with [Scala's Range](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.9/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) function:

```
@import scala.collection.immutable.Range

@for(col <- Range(0,12)) {
  <td>
    @if(col % 2 == 0) {
      @{val letter = someMap(col)
        <div class="z@(letter)@(letter)s"></div>
      }
    }
  </td>
}
```