# Play! framework: define a variable in template?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, template-engine

I'm passing to a template an `Event` object and what I need to do is checking `@event.getSeverity` value. if the value is positive, I want to color a specific `<div>` in green. if the value is negative I want to color a specific `<div>` in red.

I couldn't find a way to define a variable. is it possible? it should be I think.
anyhow, what's the simplest way accomplishing this?

thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As stated in the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTemplates) you can use the `@defining` helper.

```
@defining(if (event.getSeverity > 0) "green" else "red") { color =>
    <div style="background-color: @color">foo</div>
}
```

Or you can use a `reusable block`

```
@severityColor(event: Event) = @{
    if (event.getSeverity > 0) "green" else "red"
}

<div style="background-color: @severityColor(event)">foo</div>
```

Comment: Note that the reusable block is run every time. This may make it impractical for including data that must be calculated. But given how messy defining can be, you could consider creating a reusable block that generates the data on the first run and uses the cached copy in the future. However, this complicates the reusable blocks. Hopefully a future version of Play will make it cleaner to define variables.

Comment: Does this really mean the template compiler will not allow simply placing scala code within the html `style` attribute?

Comment: How do you use this block?

Comment: Can you then call color repeatedly in the template?

Answer (score 10):

Another variant. Works fine if declared after import section. Otherwise may cause some errors ("value not found")

```
@import play.i18n.Messages
@import models.Customers

@customers = @{Customers.allAccepted()}

...

@if(customers.size()>0) {
    <ul>
        @for(customer <- customers) {
            <li>
                <a href="/filters/customer/@customer.id">@customer.name</a>
            </li>
        } 
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to refer to the defined variable as @customers?

Comment: It is already reffered as `customers`. Inside the `@for()` statement. (You should use only one `@` sign per whole statement.)

Answer (score 9):

try this in scala template

```
@import java.math.BigInteger; var i=1; var k=1
```

and for string

```
@import java.lang.String; val name="template"
```

in question aspect

```
@import java.lang.String; var color="red"
@if(event.getSeverity>0){
@{color="green"}
}
<div style="background-color: @color">foo</div>
```

Comment: very nice! Inside the template you can change the variable `@{i=5}`

Comment: How would this actually work?

Comment: @matt check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031146/declare-variable-in-a-play2-scala-template/21397683#21397683

Comment: how does it address the conditional aspect of this question though?!

Answer (score 2):

"*for*" comprehensions can be also useful some times:
`@for(id <- products.keys;
      product = products(id);
      author = product.author.getOrElse("N/A")) {...
  @product.name
  ...
  @author`