# Accessing value by javascript Play Framework/Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

First of all I am using Play framework with scala.

I am creating a graph and with the node id I would like to show some information at the same page.

In order to do that, first I need to get `node.name` but for some reasons `@node.name` function is not working. When searching for it I learnt that it's because play is server-side and js is client-side. However I need to get the data somehow.

I also cannot access:

```
var html = "<h4>" + node.name + "</h4><b> connections:</b><ul><li>"
```

**How can I access this through the view?**

---

My second question is after reaching the js `node.name`, I need to access to controller and do the same action one more time but this time with the new `node.name` .

---

*View Part:*

```
onClick: function(node) {
  @node.name
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Is this code in your controller? And are the node variable in scope? If so this should be perfectly legal code, since it will be evaluated as pure scala.

2) The templates are a different story however. You probably know they parse everything as normal html, unless escaped. To use a variable you have to bring it into scope by either:

- defining a 'constructor' for the template at the absolute beginning of the file:

  `@(node : Node)`

  `...`

  `@node.name // later in the file`

See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates

- or define a variable inside the template:

  `@defining( Get.node.from.somewhere ) { node =>`

  ```
      @node.name
  ```

  `}`

See [Play! framework: define a variable in template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056747/play-framework-define-a-variable-in-template)

If you did either of the two, you should have no problem accessing the `node` variable. Even in scripts. But note that external scripts does not have access to the same variables. It is thus very common to use inline scripts or import it as another template if you need to access a variable from JavaScript.

**Edit**: I've made a gist of a template, controller and routes file: https://gist.github.com/Jegp/5732033

Comment: 1)this code is in my view page and its js. how can i import as another template and then access it ?

Comment: Either you can embed the javascript in your play html-/template-file or define an entirely new template that can be included using the normal @ syntax. This is actually also a pretty good practice when it comes to serving the webpage, due to some magical stuff tied to the HTTP-protocol. I'd be happy to tell you more if you're interested.

Comment: Sure i would like to learn okey that's what i did so far . main.scala page : <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.SupertrackController.javascriptRoutes"></script> @helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
  routes.javascript.SupertrackController.supertrack(id)
).--------------- controllers------------- def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>

  Ok(
    Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
      supertrack(id)
    )
  ).as("text/javascript")
}

Comment: but i have some problems with id actually in all examples , there is no id field and i couldn't find out how to make it.

Comment: These slides gives excellent advice for HTTP-performance: http://www.igvita.com/slides/2013/fluent-perfcourse.pdf

Comment: And regarding your example: Did you try and print out the resulting javascript from the javascriptRoutes action? And have you tried using the javascript console in firefox or chrome to debug the methods?

Comment: i can get the result via javascript only problem is passing it to the controller , i am trying to implement javascritprouting but couldn't manage it yet

Comment: I normally implement it like they describe in the article here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting  Just leave it plain inside the template, don't wrap it in a <script></script> tag. I've made an example of the controller, template and routes available here: https://gist.github.com/Jegp/5732033

Comment: Thank you jens i implemented everything like you do although i am not getting any error , i am not able to reach to ajax code somehow

Comment: and how i can reach to my controller for rendering the page with new id.jsRoutes.controllers.TrackController.Track(node.id).ajax({
 success: function(data) {
 alert("Success");
 
 } // i would like to  pass the id to the controller and render the page with the new track id

Comment: Argh.. I made a few error in the code - the reference to the javascript route would have to be "myRoutes.controllers.MyController" instead of "myRoutes.controllers.Something" of course. My bad! But try doing it one step at the time: Is the request received in the controller? Try a simple `println` statement to see if the data gets there. If it does try to make sure the call is actually a success so the `success` method is actually called. Hope that helpes :-)

Comment: It works know i dont remember how i fixed it but works =) thank you so much for your interest.