# Defining and editing variables inside template

Tags: java, scala, playframework

In my play app I'm trying to offer the user the oppotunity to edit a specific item he selects from a table by clicking on a button in the same table row as the item.

To be more precise the user will edit the students that have enrolled for an exam. After clicking on the exam he wants to edit a modal will open. Inside the modal a table will show all available students with a checked checkbox for students which are already enrolled.

My only problem is: How do I pass the modal the id of the exam the user wants to edit? As far as I've researched I cant't define and edit variables inside of the template. In Angular I would just modify a variable in the scope.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: That button in the table row, how are you triggering the modal to show? (onclick=xxx(), jQuery click event listener, ?)

Comment: Right now it's just data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" in the button tag. But I'm open to doing it differently if that would be easier. The modal is a standard bootstrap modal by the way. I do realize I could probably solve this whole problem by redirecting the user to a new page with a new route and the examId as parameter but I want to do it on the same page in the modal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056747/play-framework-define-a-variable-in-template/22045880#22045880 check the comment on this post you can update variable

Answer (score 0):

The general principle of moving initialization data from the back-end to the front-end is to inject it into the markup someplace, using the templating engine. In your case, in whatever loop you're using in your template to render the table rows, you simply drop the ID in it's own cell in the table,  in a `class` or `id` attribute, or maybe most appropriately, in a `data-` attribute on the table row. I would say each of these options is pretty much equivalent, mostly differing aesthetically.

Then, in your click handler, you just use a relative selector on the event target to pull the ID into your script, wherever you stashed it.

The other approach is to render your table on the front-end, pulling this information from the back-end via API, in the style of a single-page app. Then, that association between ID and data lives in the model before its even rendered. This may be overkill for this one example, but if you've got rich interactivity with a dozen of these sorts of screens, I think this is a much more scalable approach.