# How to define variable in play scala template

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I want to define this Java variable

```
int x = 0; 
x = x + 1;
```

How is it in Play Scala Template??

I already tried this for defining:

```
@import scala.Predef;
val x= 0
```

but I can't add the variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play! framework: define a variable in template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056747/play-framework-define-a-variable-in-template)

Comment: @johny thank you but it didn't work and i dont want to use defining

Comment: If you dont want to use `@defining`, you could always do something like `@var x=0; x=x+1` and later use variable `x`, which is the second answer in the linked question.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `@defining`? Is it about having too many indentations? If so, I think you shouldn't worry, because you should not need this kind of variables so often. It would be only a few. If you need more, then most probably you need to break apart your template into small pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be on the same line

```
@import scala.Predef; val x= 0
```

Also, if it is a variable, you should use `var` not `val`.

So what you need is

```
@import scala.Predef; var x= 0
```

And for reassigning:

```
@(x = x + 1)
```