# how to setup a for loop inside if statement with correct syntax Play framework Scala Template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to setup a variable in the scala template. Loop through the roles that user have , if found out the user is customer , then do something with the input. If not then do something else.

But scala isnt that simple , it won't compile on following code.

```
@var = @{ if(user != null){
    @for(role <- user.roles.filter(_.getName()=="customer")) {
        var=@customer(input)
    }
}
}

@if( var == null){
   var=@others(input)
}
```

It gives me two errors

```
t.scala.html:275:: identifier expected but 'for' found.
[error]         @for(role <- user.roles.filter(_.getName()=="customer")) 

t.scala.html:278: expected start of definition
```

Also , is there a better way to do this in scala ? Thanks

My reference : [Scala template set variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631861/scala-template-set-variable)

Update: 
My goal was trying to do something like below , but in scala template:

```
result=null
for role in User.roles:
    if(role == "customer"):
        result=customer(xyz)
        break
if(result==null):
    result = others(xyz)
```

Comment: You can't assign vals and vars in a twirl template like that, first of all.

Comment: I am trying to hack around ,I read some stackoverflow post , they say can assign variable like this ? reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631861/scala-template-set-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare a variable do

```
@import scala.Any; var result:Any=null //where Any is the datatype accoding to your requirement
```

To reassign its value do

```
@{result = "somevalue"}
```

So the solution accoding to the pseudo you provided

```
@import java.lang.String; var result:String=null
@import scala.util.control._;val loop = new Breaks;

 @loop.breakable {
     @for(role <- roleList) {

         @if(role.equals("customer")) {
             @{
                 result = "somevalue"
             }

             @{loop.break};

         }
     }
 }

  @if(result==null){
      @{result="notfound"}
  }
```

Also check [Similar1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056747/play-framework-define-a-variable-in-template),[Similar2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031146/declare-variable-in-a-play2-scala-template/21397683#21397683)

Answer (score 2):

To set up a for loop inside of an if statement in a Scala template, you don't need to assign a variable. You can simply use an `if` block in the template where you want to display stuff. For example

```
@if(user != null) {
    @for(role <- user.roles.filter(_.getName()=="customer")) {
        @customer(input)
        @* Do other stuff related to 'role' and 'input' here *@
    }
} else {
    @* Do something else *@
}
```

For further reference I encourage you to look at the [documentation for Play templates](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplates). If you really want to define a variable you could do it using the `defining` helper:

```
@defining(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName()) { fullName =>
    <div>Hello @fullName</div>
}
```

Instead of defining a variable you could also define a **resusable block**, which might be useful in your case. For example,

```
@customer_loop(input: String) = {
    @if(user != null) {
        @for(role <- user.roles.filter(_.getName()=="customer")) {
            @customer(input)
            @* Do other stuff related to 'role' and 'input' here *@
        }
    } else {
        @* Do something else *@
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it's a little bit offset than my goal. Could you take a look on my pseudo code above. Thanks

Comment: @runcode Is `result` some attribute of one of your models? Or is it simply a local variable used in your view template?

Comment: yes the result is just simply a local variable in the view template

Comment: I know this probably isn't the answer you are looking for, but the code you added above doesn't look like something that belongs in the view. The best practices for web frameworks like Play and Rails often encourage you to keep logic out of the views. Perhaps it would be better to abstract that functionality into a helper method, which you could then call from your view?