# Play and Scala: How to Declare val in view template

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

How to declare val or var in view template? 
I've have tried below code but looks like play scala can't recognize it and getting error

"not found: value snoops"

```
<div class="thumbImg">
        @{val snoops: Object= Snoop.findOneById(activity.activities.head.snoopId)}
        @snoops.userId
</div>
```

Comment: Check this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031146/declare-variable-in-a-play2-scala-template

Answer (score 2):

Valid way to do that is using `defining` as [showed in docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplates), anyway often it's better to do that in the controller and then pass to view as an argument.

Comment: thanks, now the result is :
Snoop(5327e4c19b82377ee0c85f65,5327e4b99b82377ee0c85f63,5023cb91e4b0c82863a116c3)

the code is :
@defining( Snoop.findOneById(activity.activities.head.snoopId) ) { snoop =>@snoop}

Question : how can I access the 2 value?

Comment: Use `{ snoop =>@snoop.userId}`

Comment: tried that already and getting :
value userId is not a member of Option[models.Snoop]

Here my DB:
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5327e4c19b82377ee0c85f65"),
   "_t": "models.Snoop",
   "propertyId": ObjectId("5327e4b99b82377ee0c85f63"),
   "groupId": ObjectId("5023cb91e4b0c82863a116c3"),
   "userId": ObjectId("5023cb91e4b0c82863a116c1")

Answer (score 0):

try this in scala template

```
@import java.math.BigInteger; val i=1; val k=1
```

if you want string then

```
@import java.lang.String; val name="template"
```