# Error not found: value a

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

I have defined a variable

```
@(mapCollectionCount: Map[String, String]) //values coming from controller
@{var a=0} 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var r=@mapCollectionCount.get("receipts"); 
  r=r.toLocaleString();
</script>
<div> @a<div> //gives me error not found: value a
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @FatimaKhan good question.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is that, although `var a` is defined in a block, but that scope finishes before you actually use `a`.

Use `defining`:

```
@(mapCollectionCount: Map[String, String]) //values coming from controller
@defining(0) { a => 
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  var r=@mapCollectionCount.get("receipts"); 
  r=r.toLocaleString();
 </script>
 <div> @a<div> //shouldn't give error
}
```

Also check this answer:

[Declare variable in a Play2 scala template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031146/declare-variable-in-a-play2-scala-template)