# java play framework access HashMap in template

Tags: java, templates, hashmap, playframework-2.0

I have a tag like this

```
   public class AcsTag {


         public static String getStyles(String paramter) {
             return hashMap<String, String>()

             }

         }
     }
```

I can access this tag in template (scala.html) like this

```
 @import com.twago.fms.shared.ui.AcsTag


 @AcsTag.getStyles(paramter)
```

getStyles method return a HasMap, I want to store that hashMap in a variable and then later get value from this hash map by key. I do want to iterate over map . I specifically want to access values by key.

following code i tried but always give error

> "map not defined"

```
  map =@{AcsTag.getStyles(paratmeter))}
  @{map.get("themeColor")}
```

error "map not defined"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare variable in a Play2 scala template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031146/declare-variable-in-a-play2-scala-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To declare a variable, you have to set at the top of your template:

```
@yourValue = @{yourExpression}
```

So, to declare a `map` value, you should do:

```
@map = @{AcsTag.getStyles(parameter)}
```

Then you'll be able to use yout `map` value anywhere in your template. Eg:

```
<div class="@map.get("themeColor")">...</div>
```